# Interlocked.Read/Exchange for longs on 64-bit architectures

Tags: c#, multithreading, atomic, interlocked

Is `Interlocked.Read(ref long)` "optimized away" on 64-bit architectures? I.e. if I am writing a library which could be used by both architectures, should I be concerned about performance impact of using `Interlocked.Read` unnecessarily on 64-bit CPUs?

I thought about using something like this, so I am wondering if this makes sense:

```
    // X64 is a preprocessor constant set for x64 builds  

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static long Read(ref long address)
    {
#if X64
        // atomic on 64-bit processors
        return address;
#else
        // if I got it right, this creates a full memory barrier
        return Interlocked.Read(ref address);
#endif
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Write(ref long address, long value)
    {
#if X64
        // atomic on 64-bit processors
        address = value;
#else
        // if I got it right, this creates a full memory barrier
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref address, value);
#endif
    }
```

Comment: You should never have to worry about "performance impact of using `Interlocked.Read`"

Comment: @Henk: I thought it was "don't optimize too soon", not "don't optimize ever, period". If multiple threads are using this code concurrently, I don't see the need to have a full memory barrier on each access. Furthermore, number of PCs having 32-bit processors is already low enough, and is only going to be lower.

Comment: Of course I was exaggerating but you should really demonstrate this to be the choke point. I would assume Interlocked knows about the needs of the target platform, and only bother with this after profiling points to it. And even though I don't know your code I'd say that's very unlikely.

Comment: It is an *intrinsic* to the x64 jitter.  The methods disappear completely and you get a single CPU instruction.  XCHG for the write, LOCK CMPXCHG for the read.  Highly optimized, not free.

Comment: @Hans: thanks! Yes, I went through the code and saw that `Read` is actually `CompareExchange(ref value, 0, 0);`. I presumed it's an intrinsic, but it's the actual memory barrier which bothers me. Of course, not "bothers me" as in "gives me sleepless nights" :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are concerned unnecessarily of the performance impacts of `Interlocked` because `Interlocked` doesn't *just* perform an atomic action on values, it also ensures that the value is *visible* to all threads (sequential consistency).  Let me explain.
On some architectures (some 64-bit architectures included) the value written to a memory location may be cached to improve performance.  Simply reading a value may not read the "latest" value written by another thread despite being an atomic operation.  `Interlocked` also performs a memory fence so that any operations prior to the fence have any cached values flushed to actual memory.
So, while you might improve performance a minuscule amount, you're also introducing potential race conditions.  On architectures where this isn't an issue, `Interlocked` will not perform the extra work and does the optimization for you.

Unfortunately the documentation for `Interlocked` is *still* not quite up to par on these details.  See http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx for more details on the fence involved in `Interlocked` operations.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the second question - you shouldn't be concerned with it. All you can do is determine whether reads and writes to the variable need to be thread safe and code accordingly. C# is an abstraction - you're writing for the language, not the processor. The compiler and the .NET framework worry about the processor.

64-bit reads are guaranteed to be atomic on 64-bit processors, but as you said, you're writing for both architectures. If the cost of locking is a significant impediment that you can avoid on a 64-bit architecture then that impediment will be an unsolved problem on a 32-bit architecture.

There's a cost associated with locking, but the greater cost would come from the unpredictable behavior that would come from not coding for thread safety.